# Development environment for fully qualified links in HTML, Apache

Tags: apache, localhost

I'm working on a site where some of the links are fully qualified (vs relative) in the HTML. So I keep getting redirected to the live site from my local copy. E.g., I'm on `http://example.dev/` and I click a link  `<a href="http://www.example.com/register">register</a>` so I'm sent to the live site.

Is there an Apache rule and/or something I can do in my `hosts` file so that anytime I try to go to the live site it'll redirect me to the dev site?

I tried adding `127.0.0.1 www.example.com` to my `hosts` file and this to my v-hosts conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80 *443>
  ServerName www.example.com
  RedirectMatch permanent ^/(.*) http://example.dev/$1
</VirtualHost>
```

My goal is to not have to make any adjustments to the source code/markup to fix this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache uses `mod_rewrite` only for incoming URLs. You have to use a different technique for outbound URLs. Here are some options:

- Try [mod_substitute](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_substitute.html) to find and rewrite URLs within pages.
- I think [mod_proxy_html](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_html.html) could work, but it was developed by a third party and the documentation is all over.
- The non-Apache way: Generate links using server-side code based on a flag that indicates if you are in production or development.

I think `mod_substitute` would be the easiest. It should look something like this:

```
<Location />
    AddOutputFilterByType SUBSTITUTE text/html
    Substitute s/www.example.com/example.dev/n
</Location>
```

Comment: You're a beast. Worked like a charm. Just stuck it in my v-host config. I'd rather my computer take any requests for example.com and redirect them to example.dev, but this works.